# Insert to MySQL fails on Debian when using "lines terminated by"

Tags: python, linux, debian, mysql-python

If run the code below on Debian 9, nothing happened. No error message, just run my code, but when i want open the datatable, it is empty. In Windows 7 I get always the good result.

Here my code which part is give me this empty result.. (but my "create table" part is working well).

```mysql
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
        user='root',
        passwd='1234',
        db='database1')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = """ load data local infile '/usr/src/Python-2.7.13/output.csv' 
    into table ARRIVALS
    character set latin1
    fields terminated by ';'
    enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\r\n'
    ignore 1 lines;
    """
    cursor.execute(query)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Why does Debain fail to execute the code?

Comment: Could be an issue with line termination. What happens if you delete the second to last line in the `query`?

Comment: What do you think exactly, what i have to delete? I tried with cmod+x and others but i cant understand why it isn't working, when it is running in windows7 easily.

Comment: Delete `lines terminated by '\r\n'`.

Comment: If i delete this line, it is working, thank you!! But is is a little bit strange for me, why it isn't working with lines terminated by '\r\n'?

Comment: Line terminations are different in Linux, they are just '\n', which is what MySQL uses by default. If you tell MySQL to use '\r\n' it doesn't detect the line endings, and since you are also telling it to ignore 1 line, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: And what is the better, if i am delete this line, or just use : "lines terminated by '\n'?

Comment: I would just delete it, but if you want to keep it as a reminder that's fine too.